# Contact-less liquid level indicator

Tags: sensor, measurement, infrared, water

I am developing a Liquid level indicator to be used for my lab breaker.
The purpose is to get real time liquid level data on computer for analysis.

I have searched for many liquid detectors, but mostly they use ultrasonic sensor on the top of container as shown below, but I want a sensor that could be fixed at the bottom of the container (not in contact with liquid) instead of at the top.

What technique/Principle or type of sensor could be used in this case.

Edit:- I want to know the level of any kind of liquid at any given temperature.
[image: Existing technique available]

[image: Required a sensor that could be attached at bottom of jar]

Thanks

Comment: If it is the level you are concerned, then a weight sensor can do. Why not UV by the way?

Comment: If we use weight sensor then will the type of fluid/liquid inside breaker not affect the readings?

Comment: I thought you said water. Of course, the weight will change with the type of liquid. But, the program can be calibrated for different type of liquids .

Comment: Can UV be used,as the sensor has to be at the bottom of container?

Comment: if you meant, UV intensity sensor, i am not sure. I think it may need constant light source so that only the effect of liquid should be sensed by the UV sensor. Outdoor light may also be monitored for cancelling the defect, But, i am not sure. I will leave that to experts

Comment: Look for ultrasonic sensors.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Will Ultrasonic sensor work below container?

Comment: If you choose the right one, of course

Comment: You might also be able to use piezoelectric sensor to detect the sonar reflection from the surface. (Pulse the sensor and time the reflection.)

Comment: Notice that all time-difference based sensors will, just as weight sensors, depend on the physical properties of your liquid. For example, sound travels at different speeds through oil and water, so your Ultrasonic sensor will need to be calibrated for every liquid you use. If you restrict yourself to water, as you said, then things get a lot easier. **Are you only measuring water, or are there potentially very different liquids in the container? Why do you want to measure from below?**

Comment: do you need accurate level on the full range or just at certain thresholds?

Comment: Accurate level on full range

Comment: Load cell.? ...

Comment: @Ankesh kumar Jaisansaria: See similar or duplicate question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/190000/water-level-sensor-circuit/190016#190016

Comment: It's not, because this one seems to be for all liquids, and the other is for water only.

Comment: @Pierre: OP here mentions "water" as liquid whose level is to be measured and BTW measuring methods in other answers work for non-water liquids too. So it's very well a duplicate question.

Comment: Main reason for me asking this as a separate question is because I specifically require the sensor to be placed at the bottom of the container.

Comment: @Curd you're right, he mentions "water" (but he precise liquid), and other solutions work for non-water liquids too... But it seems that he want to measure differents liquids not always the same. In fact it's still unclear.

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria please, can you answer? do you want to measure different types of liquid or in different temperature conditions?

Comment: @Pierre: yes. It's a problem that people don't ask exact questions on this site. It's annoying that one has ask three more questions back to find out what OPs really mean just because theay are too lazy to imagine that other people can not read their mind.

Comment: @Curd I could not have said it better, you read well in my mind, we see you're trained at

Comment: Sorry everyone for the confusion so created. I have edited my question. I want to measure level of liquid present in container. By liquid I mean any type of liquid content and at any temperature point.

Comment: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/3868/33

Comment: One _possible_ solution I can think of is using an infrared sensor. Probably requires some knowledge of radiometry, however.

Comment: How accurate?  How expensive?  etc.

Comment: Good level of accuracy at lowest possible price

Comment: You could try an optical time-of-flight sensor - see https://www.adafruit.com/product/3316 for example. It would depend on the reflection of the liquid/air boundary.

Answer (score 3):

I guess a pressure sensor and a load sensor do the job.

A differential pressure sensor, with one input measuring the atmospheric pressure and the other one placed at the bottom of the device should measure efficiently the pressure. The pressure can give the height of the fluid as far as it's incompressible one. This height depends on the density, which is unknown (the system have to be liquid-agnostic), but if we know the weight, we may calculate the density depending to the height.

- So we have on one hand:

$$ P = P_0 + \rho \cdot g \cdot z $$

With \$P\$ the pressure at the bottom,

\$P_0\$ the atmospheric pressure,

\$\rho\$ the volumetric mass density of the fluid,

\$g\$ the gravity,

and \$z\$ the height

- And on the other hand:

$$ \rho= \frac{w}{z \cdot \pi R^2} $$

With \$w\$ the weight,

\$R\$ the radius of your container, which is considered as a cylinder

We can now calculate \$z\$.

Edit: I didn't understand if you want to measure always the same liquid (you said you may not measure water), or if you measure different liquids. This answer is for measuring different type of liquids, but if it's not, the load sensor is not useful you can just measure the volumetric mass density of the liquid. If you measure on different conditions of temperatures, it may be considered as different type of liquids, but you can measure the temperature and apply a coefficient of thermal expansion too.
Edit2:It's the case so this answer should work